# It is possible to detect the maximum size a Flutter app can take on the screen?

Tags: ios, flutter, fullscreen

I have a Flutter app and I need to detect whether the app is running on Full screen or not to check if Split view or Stage manager (IOS) is enabled and if the window gets resized.

The app will be used in a test situation where the user is not supposed to cheat, so the app must know if it takes up the whole screen.

The app detects if the metrics change with this function:

```
@override
  void didChangeMetrics() {
    sizeDidChange = true;
  }
```

but the problem here is that you could enter the "test situation" with an app window that is already resized so that another app can fit on the screen.

I also get the current height and width by

```
double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
```

but I need to compare it to the complete size of the screen to know if its in full screen or not.

I also know if the app has moved to the background or not with

```
@override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);

    switch (state) {
      case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
        setState(() {
          inBackground = false;
        });
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.inactive:
        setState(() {
          inBackground = true;
        });
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.paused:
        setState(() {
          inBackground = true;
        });
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.detached:
        setState(() {
          inBackground = true;
        });
        break;
    }
  }
```

but that does not detect stage manager or slide over

Comment: On iOS you should look into [automatic assessment configuration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/automaticassessmentconfiguration) - you need to apply for the entitlement but if you have it, it will make it much easier to deliver exams, however you need some form of proctoring for exams anyway, as the user may have access to other devices if they aren't supervised.

Comment: Thank you @Paulw11 ! Do you know anything about the application process? I don't have an Apple Developer Account yet so I can't view the application form.

Comment: It asks you to confirm that your app delivers academic exams to students and some details about your organisation and your app; who you are and what your app does